# Blogger.com redirect url - How?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i need to redirect urls like these:

```
http://domain.com/2014/08/post1-url.html
http://domain.com/2014/05/post2-url.html
http://domain.com/2013/04/post3-url.html
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/post1-url
http://domain.com/post2-url
http://domain.com/post3-url
```

Can anybody help and tell me what I need to write in my `.htaccess` file? Thanks!

I tried it with this, but it is not working: (first 6 lines are from wordpress)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^domain.com/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ domain.com/$3 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.+?)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Your regex isn't right as you cannot match hostname in the `RewriteRule`.